# Relative imports in Python 2.5

Tags: python, import, relative-path, python-2.5

I know that there are lots of questions about the same import issues in Python but it seems that nobody managed to provide a clear example of correct usage.

Let's say that we have a package `mypackage` with two modules `foo` and `bar`. Inside `foo` we need to be able to access `bar`.

Because we are still developing it, `mypackage` is not in `sys.path`.

We want to be able to:

- import `mypackage.foo`
- run `foo.py` as a script and execute the sample usage or tests from the `__main__` section.
- use Python 2.5

How do we have to do the import in foo.py in order to be sure it will work in all these cases.

```
# mypackage/__init__.py
...

# mypackage/foo/__init__.py
...

# mypackage/bar.py
def doBar()
    print("doBar")

# mypackage/foo/foo.py
import bar # Fails with module not found
import .bar # Fails due to ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

def doFoo():
    print(doBar())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doFoo()
```

Comment: I believe you have to distinguish importable modules from scripts. I'm not sure I agree with that design, but that's my understanding of it.

Comment: Usually, when you need to import packages from upper level, you are doing something wrong: would you instead want to use `bar` as a library rather than as a submodule to mypackage? I.e. could you refactor mypackage into mypackage1 and mypackage2 where mypackage2 (with foo) imports mypackage1 (with bar)?

Answer (score 32):

Take a look at the following info from [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name):

> Relative imports use a module's `__name__` attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to `'__main__'`) then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

When you run `foo.py` as a script, that module's `__name__` is `'__main__'`, so you cannot do relative imports.  This would be true even if `mypackage` was on `sys.path`.  Basically, you can only do relative imports from a module if that module was imported.

Here are a couple of options for working around this:

1) In `foo.py`, check if `__name__ == '__main__'` and conditionally add `mypackage` to `sys.path`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os, sys
    # get an absolute path to the directory that contains mypackage
    foo_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), __file__))
    sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(foo_dir, '..', '..')))
    from mypackage import bar
else:
    from .. import bar
```

2) Always import `bar` using `from mypackage import bar`, and execute `foo.py` in such a way that `mypackage` is visible automatically:

```
$ cd <path containing mypackage>
$ python -m mypackage.foo.foo
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that is still unclear is the detection of the path to the package. I will check tomorrow and be back with the results.

Comment: @sorin - I have just edited my answer so you can get the path to mypackage regardless of where you call foo.py from.

Comment: On Windows I found few cases where `getcwd()` is not providing the script directory. There are at least 3 ways of calling a python script: "python a.py", "a.py", and running from Windows Explorer (eventually via pythonw)

Comment: @sorin - Unfortunately I am only able to test on Linux, the behavior I see is that `__file__` is either an absolute path, or the path to `foo.py` from `os.getcwd()`.  In both of these cases, `foo_dir` is an absolute path to the directory containing `foo.py`.  Not sure how it needs to change if this isn't the case for Windows.

Comment: @fj I discovered that your approach doesn't work if inside foo.py I need to use something from bar, take a look at the updated example.

Comment: @sorin - If you need to use `doBar` from bar, you either need to import it to foo's namespace with `from mypackage.bar import doBar` or use `from mypackage import bar` and call it as `bar.doBar()`.

Answer (score 7):

My solution looks a bit cleaner and can go at the top, with all the other imports:

```
try:
   from foo import FooClass
except ModuleNotFoundError:
   from .foo import FooClass
```