# Django, GAE, numpy: cannot import name multiarray

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, numpy

I can't get numpy working with Django (django-nonrel) and Google App Engine. Here's the project structure:

```
gae/
  virtualenv_directory/
  project/
    app/
      views.py
      algorithm.py
      ...
    lib/
      nltk/
      numpy/
      ...
    nltk_data/
    settings.py
```

All third-party libraries are installed in lib/ directory using command: "pip install -t . package".
Also, settings.py contains the line:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'lib'))
```

In views.py I call a function from algorithm.py, which uses nltk. However, when calling it as a user (on development server) I get the following error:

> Exception Type:   ImportError
> Exception Value:  cannot import name multiarray
> Exception Location:   /home/me/gae/project/lib/numpy/core/**init**.py in , line 6
> Python Executable:    /home/me/gae/virtualenv_directory/bin/python
> Python Version:   2.7.3

Traceback ends with line:

> File "/home/me/gae/project/lib/numpy/core/**init**.py" in
> 6. from . import multiarray

Local vars:

> **file** None
> absolute_import None
> **package** None
> **path** None
> **name** None
> **version** None
> **doc** None
> print_function None

[Ultimate answer to relative python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/ultimate-answer-to-relative-python-imports) says that:

> Relative imports use a module's **name** attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '**main**') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

So it seems that the error is caused by **name** equal to 'None'. But what is the reason for it?

In ./manage.py shell I can import numpy.core.multiarray or call the function from algorithm.py without any errors.

I've also tried to use GAE numpy, adding the following lines to app.yaml:

```
- name: numpy
  version: latest
```

But the result was another import error, that is:

> Exception Value: cannot import name scimath
> Exception Location: /home/me/gae/virtualenv_directory/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py in , line 17
> Python Executable: /home/me/gae/virtualenv_directory/bin/python
>
> /home/me/gae/virtualenv_directory/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py in 
> 17. from . import scimath as emath

Once again, all local vars mentioned above are equal to 'None'.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to run python with virtualenv activated.  This does not normally work.

Comment: Also consider using appengine_config.py for doing path manipulation rather than using your settings.py - this is run by the server before doing anything with your code.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Comment: Also watch where you put your local copy of numpy you don't want to deploy it.  You will run the production copy that is already there.

Comment: 1) Yes, virtualenv is activated when I run development server. However, deactivation results in the same error (cannot import multiarray). 2) I'm going to try appengine_config.py 3) Could you elaborate a little more on this? I have 3 copies of numpy - one in lib/ directory, one in virtualenv_directory and one global, installed without pip.

Comment: The only version of numpy that the SDK can access is the one in your lib directory.  This is what my appengine config looks like  http://pastebin.com/DvrDZxN6  .  You probably should check that the version in your lib dir can actually be used, in a python shell.

Comment: 1) Adding 'import numpy' to views.py results in the same error (multiarray) when trying to load main page. 2) I can import library from lib/ directory. 3) When 'global' version of numpy (i.e. the one installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages) is removed, virtualenv is deactivated and I append '/home/me/gae/project/lib' to sys.path in python shell, it is possible to import numpy or any other part of it. 4) Numpy version is 1.8.0, if it does matter at all.

Comment: I still don't have any idea how to fix it. Here's the log from Django: http://pastebin.com/Rhz05Vnr

Comment: Well, it works if I remove all template tags from template. '''import numpy''' stays in views.py, and I really doubt they (views.py) are called/imported when url uses direct_to_template. It's stunning.

Comment: I've downloaded django-nonrel testapp from https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-testapp, created another virtualenv, installed numpy once again with pip(1.8.0) and imported numpy in views.py. It still doesn't work: `cannot import name _umath_linalg`

Comment: Wow! It works - but I don't understand why. First, I removed numpy from lib/. Second, I've installed numpy 1.6.1 with command `sudo pip install -t . numpy==1.6.1` (being in aforementioned lib directory). The last thing was to add numpy 1.6.1 to app.yaml. I think it was some compilation-specific failure or missing user permissions (but why did it succeed during compilation?). Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Mac. You can't install numpy 1.6.1 on Mac despite using

`CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install numpy==1.6.1`

And I couldn't use the latest numpy due dependencies on `multiarray` namespace.
Besides currently GAE only supports only up to `numpy===1.6.1` hence it makes sense to have any higher version installed.

The solution was for me to install `1.6.2`, which I could install on Mac and has still the needed `multiarray`.  Now I can `import numpy` in GAE and it works.