# Cannot import local module in Python despite trying multiple suggestions

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-module

I've read through about ten posts on how to import local modules, and I'm still stumped on why this isn't working. I have an extremely simple module, actor.py, with a single class inside it:

```
class Actor(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

I'm trying to import it into another module, scraper.py, within the same directory:
[image]

Some fixes have listed not having **init**.py as being a problem with local imports, so I know that's not my problem.
Initially I tried these:

```
import actor
```

and

```
from actor import Actor
```

but it tells me that actor and Actor are unresolved references. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) tells me that's Python 2 syntax, and I'm using Python 3. That answer instead recommends that I do:

```
from .actor import Actor
```

When I run my program with that syntax, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.actor'; '__main__' is not a package
```

So I go searching again, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package) post tells me to remove the dot from 'actor,' but as stated before, I've tried that as well. My final guess was

```
from . import actor
```

but that yields

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'actor'
```

which I follow to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x), but the answers there mention circular dependencies, and I'm certain actor and scraper have none. Am I perhaps not writing my module correctly? I can't think of any other ways to write an import statement.

edit: if it helps at all, I'm using Intellij

Comment: how are you trying to run this? `'__main__' is not a package` suggests a problem with the way you are executing.

Comment: should be:  `from actor import Actor`, You import the class from a file in the same directory.

Comment: @avigil I'm running the main method inside scraper.py.

Comment: so `python -m WebScraper.scraper`? You cannot call it directly with `python scraper.py` if its part of a module.

Comment: or if you are running inside IntelliJ this is a problem with your IDE run configuration and not the code itself.

Comment: @avigil I am running inside Intellij, yes

Comment: I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm but my src folder is marked as a source root, and I have it set up so that source roots are added to PYTHONPATH. still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from WebScraper.actor import Actor`. If this doesn't work its because your package directory is not in the `PYTHONPATH`. You can set that in the [IntelliJ Python run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-python.html).

The relative import is not working for you because you are trying to run a module as a script. You can see an explanation of what is happening at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8300343/7088038. If you want relative imports to work you will have to add a `__main__.py` file to your module to allow it to be runnable, or execute from an external script where you use an absolute import so you don't clobber the package namespace.

One other stylistic note- *usually* (but not always) package names in python use all lowercase names. CamelCase is reserved for class names. So if you wanted to follow convention you would call your package `webscraper` and use `from webscraper.actor import Actor`

Answer (score 0):

To import a class into your script use:

```
from actor import Actor
```

Or to import the .py entirely (including whatever imports included in it) into the namespace use:

```
from actor import *
```

Comment: if you look through my post, you can see I already tried that to no avail

Comment: I did see that but I try it and it works. am I missing something?

Comment: If I do "from actor import Actor" it tells me actor is an unresolved reference, so that alone isn't the solution

Comment: I'll clarify the reason it didn't work in my original post

Comment: might be for using `(Object)` in class definition. New syntax in python3 done away with that.

Comment: nope, getting rid of it didn't change the unresolved reference error

Comment: hmm.. I am missing something, I created a subclass to Actor is a seperate file and I manage to import one to the other and import to a shell without a problem with the simple `from <> import *' could you upload scraper.py, perhaps and I'll try to recreate it on my machine?