# Running python package sub-module independently for self-test; import path kludge

Tags: python

I often write self-test code at the bottom of a module, i.e.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

.
.
.
```

I want to keep this in the module so that if I modify it I can still run self-test on it.  The module is part of a package.  So there are inter-package references that need to be resolved; but these are resolved differently if I'm importing the package versus running the module standalone.

I end up with a kludge like this at the top of my modules, which is certainly ugly and probably not 'pythonic':

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from CovSample import CovSample
    from ArrayByRow import ArrayByRow    
else:

    from CEOpt import CovSample
    from CEOpt import ArrayByRow
```

This works - if I'm importing package CEOpt - the else-branch references work, and if I'm running standalone - the direct module name imports work.  But it's not pretty I would like one import statement for the inter-package calls that still work in standalone module test.  Is that possible?

Comment: Note that a nicer way to do *within*-package imports is to do them relatively (i.e. without having to name `CEOpt` explicitly) and make that relativity explicit using prefixed dots: `from .CovSample import CovSample` and `from .ArrayByRow import ArrayByRow`.  However, that doesn't work when `__name__=='__main__'` either, so it doesn't answer your question.  I too would be very interested to hear if there was a universal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/ultimate-answer-to-relative-python-imports) that there's no universal way that will work in both cases, `__name__=='__main__'` and `__name__!='__main__'`.

What I do is the following:  define a `Test()` function inside each submodule (so `CEOpt.CovSample.Test()` and `CEOpt.ArrayByRow.Test()`).  Then create a single `CEOpt/__main__.py` file, which is the only file from the `CEOpt` package that you will ever "run" directly (that particular filename ensures that it is the one that gets run when you say `python -m CEOpt` from your shell). This file must `import CEOpt` explicitly by name, but at least now that only has to happen in one place (the other files can use relative imports with prefixed dot syntax—for example `from .CovArray import CovArray`).  Now program the logic of `__main__.py` such that it responds to subcommands passed in via `sys.argv`, selecting which submodule's `Test()` function to run.

So for example, the syntax `python -m CEOpt test CovArray` (or equivalently `%run CEOpt/__main__ test CovArray` from an IPython prompt) would trigger `__main__.py` to call `CEOpt.CovArray.Test()`

Comment: thanks - that's a good approach.  In my case - I usually develop a module then later decide I want it to live in a package.  So I have a period of weeks or months where the module must run without the package overhead - and then I drop it in the package.  Your method would work for me if I knew I was making a package from the start.  I may have to live with my kludge or start planning my work!

Comment: Maybe you could still put the test code in `Test()`, from the beginning,  but get into the habit of saying `import thing; thing.Test()` instead of `run thing`.  Or you could create your own IPython magic `%runtest` that performs `importlib.reload(importlib.import_module(targetModuleName)).Test()` on a named target (sub-)module.  Then you only need to type `%runtest CovArray`—or, later in your development, `%runtest CEOpt.CovArray`