# Import classes from parent folder in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

In a certain programme I have an abstract class that should be implemented in two different sub-packages for different purposes. A simplified version of this structure is:

```
programme/
  __init__.py
  Abstract.py
  pkgA/
    __init__.py
    ClassA.py
  pkgB/
    __init__.py
    ClassB.py
```

Up to Python 3.2 (I believe), it was possible to import the Abstract class within the a subfolder with [a relative reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714647/2066215):

`from .. import Abstract`

Which with Python 3.6 devolves the error message:

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

The [classical (and ugly) alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331002/2066215) is to add the parent folder to the path at run time:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/..')
from programme import Abstract
```

But this also fails:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'programme'`

How is this now done with Python 3.6? Preferably without modifying the path at run time.

Comment: Please re-read the answer you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331002/2066215 It doesn't mention `parent` anywhere, nor is there a file or folder called `parent` in your directory structure, so there is `No module named 'parent'`, but you can `import Abstract`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @ForceBru, now corrected.

Comment: @Chris That question is on Python 2.7. The mechanisms for that version no longer apply to more recent versions.

Comment: Okay, then [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/354577)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a __init__.py at the top level, programme/__init__.py, then import in 
the sub-module from programme.

***Example:***

```py
# programme/__init__.py
from .Abstrac import Abstract
```

```py
# programme/Abstract.py
class Abstract:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Abstract')
```

```py
# programme/pkgA/ClassA.py
from programme import Abstract

class ClassA(Abstract):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ClassA()
```

Note, if you running as a script you should do:

```sh
$ cd programme
$ python -m programme.classA.ClassA
Abstract
```

Comment: This solution does not work. Running as you suggest returns the error: `Error while finding module specification for 'programme.classA.ClassA' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'programme')`. Running `classA.py` from the `pkgA` folder returns: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'programme'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to a level higher than programme.

This needs to be added to the code:

```
import os, sys
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), __file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(current_dir, '..', '..')))
from programme import Abstract
```

This has worked when doing `python3.7 ClassA.py` on `programme/pkgA` and it was picked from this response: [Ultimate answer to relative python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/ultimate-answer-to-relative-python-imports)

Comment: Indeed this works. But it would be much cleaner without having to fiddle with the path at run time.